# .getJSON won't succeed even though URL works

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

HTML

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1>Wikipedia Viewer</h1>
            <form id="userInput">
                <input id="query" type="text" name="userInput" value="" placeholder="Search">
                <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" name="send" value="Click!">
            </form>
            <a id="randomArticle" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"><i class="fa fa-random fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="results">
         </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript

```
 var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&datatype=json&callback=?&search=";
    var userQuery = "";
    var html = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#userInput").submit(function (e) {
            userQuery = document.getElementById("query").value;
            $.getJSON(url + userQuery, function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
                    html = '<article><a href="' + data[3][i] + '"target="_blank"><h3>' + data[1][i] + '</h3><p>' + data[2][i] + '</p></a></article>';
                    $(".results").append(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

When I get to the .getJSON it just won’t succeed, I have tested the URL and the JSON comes up in browser but the request using Jquery just won’t work.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(data)`.

Comment: Could you add the relevant HTML?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki nothing it won't output anything I also tried an alert() and it didn't do anything.

Comment: You're not doing anything to prevent the `<form>` from submitting.

Comment: You can either put `e.preventDefault();` just after your `submit()`, or change your HTML to not use `type="submit"` on your `input`.

Comment: @Dalorzo don't be so sure.

Comment: Thank you @pmahomme and Pointy that was exactly the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to add a jQuery [**`preventDefault()`**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp) Method to your button click event as in:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#userInput").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        userQuery = document.getElementById("query").value;
        $.getJSON(url + userQuery, function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
                html = '<article><a href="' + data[3][i] + '" target="_blank"><h3>' + data[1][i] + '</h3><p>' + data[2][i] + '</p></a></article>';
                $(".results").append(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you log the success and fail method. Possibly, there can be `Cross Origin` issue, if that so then you need to add cors at server level.

You can log the success and failure as mentioned http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
  console.log( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
  });

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.complete(function() {
  console.log( "second complete" );
});
```